# how to add query for simple cache in ignite web console

Tags: ignite

I am a new developer for apache ignite, When I use web console to query cache. but report the table *** not found. steps as below:

step 1, I start a ignite server node with default port 47500, then create a cache "vapp_user" without dbfactory/dbstore, then put 10000 records to this cache, the key type is Long, value type is User pojo.

step 2, I run the mongodb, the web console agent, web console backend and frontend with dev mode

step 3, in the configuration page, I created the cluster with static ip, and created the cache vapp_user with the domain model with User. the screen as below:
[model screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewr9b.png)

step 4, then add a query with sql "select * from vapp_user" or "select * from User", system reported the error "table *** not found." but I can query related result with Adding Scan.
[Query Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk03D.png)

I didn't use import from database to create model, the table need to how to create? use which database?

How to execute the query for the simple cache without any db?

Answer (score 1):

Check that in your cache configuration you have IndexedTypes. Something like:

```
    userCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, User.class);
```

In this case query "select * from User" should work.

Check this [example](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryDmlExample.java).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I add the indexTypes for cache "vapp_user", get the expected result.

Comment: I have another question, I add an condition id=1 for sql "select * from User where id=1", but reported the column id is not found? how to fix it? It is configured in CacheConfiguration or web console page?

Comment: The pojo User has 3 fields, they are id, name and birthday. Normally,  SqlQuery and SqlFieldsQuery don't need set special fields in java code.